# replacing whole, first matched line

Tags: shell, sed, scripting

Input file:

```
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass abcderf
```

Though, the regex seems to be correct and working, sed command does not replace matched line:

regex'es tried successfully:

```
$ grep -E '[[:space:]]*auth[[:space:]]+sufficient[[:space:]]+pam_unix.+$' input
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass abcderf
$ grep -E '^\s*auth\s+sufficient\s+pam_unix\.so.*$' input
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass abcderf
$ grep -E "^\s*auth\s+sufficient\s+pam_unix\.so.*$" input
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass abcderf
```

However, sed commands using above regex don't replace matched line as expected, with content of `P` variable:

```
$ P='auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass'

$ echo "$P"
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass

$ sed "0,/^\s*auth\s+sufficient\s+pam_unix\.so.*$/s//${P}/" input|grep -E '^\s*auth\s+sufficient\s+pam_unix\.so.*$'
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass abcderf

$ sed "0,/^[[:space:]]*auth[[:space:]]+sufficient[[:space:]]+pam_unix.*$/s//${P}/" input|grep -E '^\s*auth\s+sufficient\s+pam_unix\.so.*$'
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass abcderf
```

Comment: Could you please post samples of your input and expected output too in your question for better understanding of question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In basic regex `+` is `+`. To match one or more characters in basic regex you have to `\+`.

```
sed "0,/^[[:space:]]*auth[[:space:]]\+sufficient[[:space:]]\+pam_unix.*$/s//${P}/"
# I would keep it in ' quotes
sed '0,/^[[:space:]]*auth[[:space:]]\+sufficient[[:space:]]\+pam_unix.*$/s//'"${P}"'/'
```

But you might as well use `sed -r` or `sed -E` and use extended regex with sed, as you seem to use `\s` extensions anyway.